# long double line for title

Tags: titles, rules

How can I make a long double line for a title like the picture[image]

What I have at the moment is this:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{wasysym} 
\begin{document} 
\def\doubleunderline#1{%
\underline{\underline{#1}}} 

$\doubleunderline{ Title}$\\ 

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: This is how i start ..but the underline is not long enough.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\begin{document}

\def\doubleunderline#1{\underline{\underline{#1}}}
$\doubleunderline{ Title}$\\
\end{document}

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 2):

Like so:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\title{Title \vspace{.5em} \hrule \vspace{.2em} \hrule}
\date{}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or if you want it separate from `\title`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\title{Title}
\date{}
\maketitle

\vspace{-5em} % Without this the lines would be drawn in the body
\hrule \vspace{.2em}
\hrule
\end{document}
```